# Corrupted state exceptions (CSE) across AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, exception, corrupted-state-exception

For some background info, .NET 4.0 no longer catches CSEs by default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx

I'm working on an app that executes code in a new AppDomain.  If that code throws a CSE, the exception bubbles up to the main code if it's not handled.  My question is, can I safely assume that a CSE on the second AppDomain won't corrupt the state in the main AppDomain, and thus exit the second AppDomain and continue running the main AppDomain?

Comment: this is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62843347/1704458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a corrupted state exception, in general, you cannot assume *anything* to be true anymore. The point of these exceptions is that something has happened, usually due to buggy unmanaged code, that has violated some core assumption that Windows or the CLR makes about the structure of memory. That means that, in theory, the very structures that the CLR uses to track which app domains exist in memory *could* be corrupted. The kinds of things that cause CSEs are generally indicative that things have gone catastrophically wrong.

Having said all that, off-the-record, in some cases, you may be able to make a determination that it is safe to continue from a particular exception. An `EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW`, for example, is probably recoverable, and an `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` usually indicates that Windows caught a potential bug *before* it had a chance to screw anything up. It's up to you if you're willing to risk it, depending on how much you know about the code that is throwing the CSEs in the first place.

Comment: It would be good to have official references instead of just "taking your word for it", but it does make sense since unsafe code could do just about anything.  Thanks for covering specific exceptions which made your answer more practical.